# libssl error after upgrading Mongo

Tags: linux, ubuntu, libraries, mongodb

I upgraded to Mongo 3.4.4 by first downliading the tgz file and copying all the contents of its `bin/` folder to `/user/bin/`.

I then ran `mongo` and got:

```
mongo: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So  I ran:

```
sudo cp /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 /usr/lib/libssl.so.10
sudo cp /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.10
```

I then went to `/usr/lib/` and both files are there. I then ran mongo again and now I see:

```
mongo: /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.10: version `libcrypto.so.10' not found (required by mongo)
mongo: /usr/lib/libssl.so.10: version `libssl.so.10' not found (required by mongo)
```

The files are there. How is it possible that mongo cannot see them?

Im using Linux Mint 17.1